# When commenting on a "moderator" flag, how can I finish just with the keyboard?

Tags: support

When I flag a post "for moderator attention/other" I want to just type my comment and then commit the flag using only the keyboard. As I see it now I have to use the mouse to click on "flag question" because <kbd>enter</kbd> just inserts a break.

Additionally I have already tried <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: Check out [Keyboard shortcuts, phase one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102769/keyboard-shortcuts-phase-one).

Comment: @jokerdino thx for the pointer, that script seems like some overkill :-)

Comment: @jokerdino. Neat! Unfortunately, it looks like the script will collide with my vimium shortcuts. Oh well.